# HTML/CSS Wait until page is loaded

Tags: javascript, css, animation, html

I have a CSS animation with sound, however, when the page initially loads, the sound is delayed. I would like a way to wait until everything on the page has loaded before I load the page. How can I do this? I found one script here: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/display-loading-graphic-until-page-fully-loaded/ but I was wondering if there was something even simpler.

Comment: I noticed the page you linked uses jQuery, but it's not specified above in the tags. Are you looking for a pure JavaScript solution? Also, please post any relevant code of your own in your post so we can see what you've tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link you provided is the simplest and best way to do this. No need to look for anything else.

```
<script>
    // Wait for window load
    $(window).load(function() {
        // Animate loader off screen
        $("#loader").animate({
            top: -200
        }, 1500);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I don't see jQuery tagged in this question, so I guess you should also recommend `window.onload = function () { // code } ;`

Comment: What is the benefit of window.onload = function () { // code } ; ? Would it be beneficial to have both that code and the previous code?

Comment: The code I posted is just jQuery's way of doing ` window.onload = function () { // code }` so it would be redundant.